# Pythonで複数の出力結果から特定のIDを取得したい

Tags: python, python3

Webスクレイピングで取得したIDが複数で出力されるので、リスト化後、特定のIDを取得したいです。

実現内容

```
["12345","21234","22456"]
```

取得したいリストから `[1]` を指定して21234のIDを取得したいです。

下記のコードで行いましたが、上手く出力結果の**21234**を取得できず、エラーします。

どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

code

```
# BeautifulSoupから取得するID　WEBページにHOUSE用語が含んでいましたら、全てのID出力
for i in soup.find_all(class_=['text-box']):
    if 'HOUSE' in i.text: 
     find_id= [i.parent.parent.parent.get('id').split('-')[-1]]

　　　　　　　　print(find_id)

a=find_id[1]

print(a)
```

`print(find_id)` の結果

```
['12345']
['21234']
['22456']
```

変数aからIDを取得したプログラムを組みましたが、print(a)がエラーメッセージします。

```
a=find_id[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

それはありえないですね。print(find_id)の結果からNameErrorが発生するはずです。

print(find_id)
は、もしかしたらfind_id=...のすぐ下になっていないでしょうか？

```
ids = []
for i in soup.find_all(class_=['text-box']):
    if 'HOUSE' in i.text: 
     ids += [i.parent.parent.parent.get('id').split('-')[-1]]

print(ids[1])
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。説明不足で申し訳ありません。
print(a)は`NameError: name 'find_id' is not defined`エラーになります。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。print(find_id)の位置は本当に書いたとおりでしょうか？

Comment: 度々、すいません。FOR文の中にprint(find_id)があります。またエラー再度確認したところ`IndexError: list index out of range`と表示されます。

Comment: 聞いている理由は、['12345']
['21234']
['22456']　はリストではないから、３回プリントが行ったのでは？と思っていました。リストを作ってIDを入れると解決＾＾

Comment: 縦で下記のように出力されます。
['12345']
['21234']
['22456']

Comment: 提案を答えに書いてみました。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。リスト作成からやってみます。

Comment: 良かったら上の答えを編集しましたので、ご参考になれたらと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ上記の方法で行うと21234 21234 21234 が表示されます。一つのIDだけ取得できないでしょうか。

Comment: 失礼しました。printをforから抜けましたら21234を取得できました。+=の代入方法勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。